# Getting foreach() and ggplot2 to get along

Tags: r, foreach, ggplot2

I have a set of survey data, and I'd like to generate plots of a particular variable, grouped by the respondent's country.  The code I have written to generate the plots so far is:

```
countries <- isplit(drones, drones$v3)
foreach(country = countries) %dopar% {
  png(file = paste(output.exp, "/Histogram of Job Satisfaction in ", country$key[[1]], ".png", sep = ""))
  country.df <- data.frame(country)  #ggplot2 doesn't appreciate the lists nextElem() produces
  ggplot(country.df, aes(x = value.v51)) + geom_histogram()
  dev.off()
}
```

The truly bizarre thing?  I can run the isplit(), set `country <- nextElem(countries)`, and then run through the code without sending the foreach line - and get a lovely plot.  If I send the foreach, I get some blank .png files.

I can definitely do this with standard R loops, but I'd really like to get a better grasp on `foreach`.

Comment: Could you post some sample data?  It'd make it much easier to test.

Comment: Of course.  The honest-to-goodness data: http://drop.io/cy81s4w/asset/sample-data-rdata

Comment: I hope that using the actual data is okay - a little unusual, but it seems the most efficient.  Just use load(file.choose()) to input that data into R, then drones <- sample.  You'll also need to set output.exp to some folder where you'd like 19 .png files to show up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `print` the plot if you want it to display:

```
print(ggplot(country.df, aes(x = value.v51)) + geom_histogram())
```

By default, ggplot commands return a plot object but the command itself does not actually display the plot; that is done with the `print` command.  Note that when you run code interactively, results of commands get printed which is why you often don't need the explicit print.  But when wrapping in a `foreach`, you need to explicitly print since the results of the commands in the body will not be echoed.

Comment: Alternatively, use `ggsave`

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for the explanation - that will likely save me confusion in the future, too.  Hadley, thanks for mentioning (uh, and writing) ggsave() - it's smooth.