# Produce multiple ggplot figures within one ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use the same ggplot code to produce 8 different figures conditional upon figures in my dataframe.  Usually I would use facet_grid, but in this case, I would like to end up with a pdf of each individual figure.  For example, I would like one pdf for each row here:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
xvalue     yvalue    location    planting    crop
  1          5          A          early      corn
  2          3          A          late       corn
  6          2          A          early      soy
  7          4          A          late       soy
  4          7          S          early      corn
  2          6          S          late       corn
  3          2          S          early      soy
  5          1          S          late       soy
", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

Basic ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=xvalue, y=yvalue), data=df)
```

but instead of `facet_grid` to get the location x planting x crop combos, I want one separate pdf of each.

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19147917/2461552)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I made your MWE into a `data.table` because it's faster

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.table(read.table(text = "
            xvalue     yvalue    location    planting    crop
            1          5          A          early      corn
            2          3          A          late       corn
            6          2          A          early      soy
            7          4          A          late       soy
            4          7          S          early      corn
            2          6          S          late       corn
            3          2          S          early      soy
            5          1          S          late       soy
            ", sep = "", header = TRUE))
```

I pasted together your `planting` and `corn` information to create a separate column:

```
df[ , plantingCrop := paste(df$planting, df$crop, sep = "-") ]
```

I created an character vector that has all combinations of `planting` and `crop`. You'll see why in a second:

```
plantingCrop1 <- unique(df$plantingCrop)
```

I use `gridExtra` to create all of the plots in separate `.pdf` pages. I basically created a loop that plots as many graphs as there are characters in the `plantingCrop1` object I made above. In each loop, `dat` is the subsetted group that you want to plot, by the unique `plantingCrop` group from when we pasted the `planting` and `crop` columns together. It repeats this until everything is done.

```
pdf("plantingCrop.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(plantingCrop1)){
        dat <- subset(df, plantingCrop==plantingCrop1[i])
        cropPlot <- ggplot(dat, aes(xvalue,yvalue)) + 
                    geom_boxplot(aes(color = location)) + 
                    theme_bw() + 
                    ggtitle(bquote(atop(.("Boxplot of Stuff"), 
                          atop(italic(.(plantingCrop1[i])), "")))) +
                    labs(x = "xvalue", y = "yvalue") +
                    theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title=element_blank())
        grid.arrange(cropPlot)
        }
dev.off()
```

I also included the right way to name the files using the `plantingCrop` name as a subtitle. That's in the `ggtitle` call.

I'd encourage you to change `geom_boxplot(aes(color = location))` to `geom_boxplot(aes(fill = location)` when you have more data as it shows up on a graph better, but I left it that way for now so you can see the different groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text = "
xvalue     yvalue    location    planting    crop
  1          5          A          early      corn
  2          3          A          late       corn
  6          2          A          early      soy
  7          4          A          late       soy
  4          7          S          early      corn
  2          6          S          late       corn
  3          2          S          early      soy
  5          1          S          late       soy
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

fplot <- function(d)
  {
     require(ggplot2)
     p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = xvalue, y = yvalue)) +
             geom_point(size = 4) +
             xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10)
     file <- with(d, paste0(paste(planting, crop, location, sep = "_"), ".pdf"))
     ggsave(file, p)
  }

d_ply(df, ~ rownames(df), fplot)
```

The file names look like early_corn_A.pdf and are saved in your current working directory. I set fixed x/y limits for visual convenience. The function takes
a one-row data frame as input and outputs a plot in pdf form. The `plyr::d_ply()` function processes each row of the data frame and produces a separate plot per row.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem.

I simply used

> gridExtra()

Available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html)

Then, I used another package named :

> cowplot()

Available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html)

Then I followed the steps [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page-r-software-and-data-visualization).

And it worked like a charm. :D

Hope it helps.