# How to create a plot with multiple figures(multiplot) for each level of a factor(n>1) and save in a file in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

The problem is that I have a data set where I want to plot n "y" variables against one "x" variable in ggplot2. I want to then make multiple multiplots for k levels of a factor and save all k mulitplots in one file.

For example, consider the mtcars data. I can generate a figure of y=hp vs. x=mph and a separate figure of y=wt vs. x=mph and put them together into one multiplot by:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

a1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp))+geom_point()
b1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,wt))+geom_point()
p <- grid.arrange(a1,b1)
```

OK, now I want to create the same multiplot but for different levels of the factor "am". (Edit: I would like to have one multiplot for am=0 and one multiplot for am=1) I found a solution for creating plots based on a factor and saving in one file [here][How subset a data frame by a factor and repeat a plot for each subset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146665/how-subset-a-data-frame-by-a-factor-and-repeat-a-plot-for-each-subset)

I tried to modify the above code for my problem, the following is my attempt:

```
plots = mtcars %>%
group_by(am) %>%
do({a = a1 %+% .
b = b1 %+% .
plots = p %+% .})
```

I also tried:

```
plots = mtcars %>%
group_by(am) %>%
do({a1 = ggplot(.,aes(mpg,hp))+geom_point()
b1 = ggplot(.,aes(mpg,wt))+geom_point()
p = grid.arrange(a1,b1)})
```

in both situations I have the error

```
Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2
```

I understand that there is a data frame problem. But I don't understand why it is a problem in my code and not in the sample code. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Following Tims post below, gather can be used to achieve the end result that I am looking for.

```
library(tidyr)
dat1 <- mtcars %>% 
gather(key, value, hp, wt)

p <- ggplot(dat1,aes(mpg, value)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free_y") 

plots = dat1 %>%
group_by(am) %>%
do(
plots = p %+% .)

pdf()
plots$plots
dev.off()
```

However, this doesn't allow much in the way of customization for the individual plots for different variables. Say I wanted to add a line using geom_vline to plot hp vs. mpg but not have it on plot wt vs. mpg. I'm not sure you could do that in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question I think you are making this a little more complicated than it needs to be. You are wanting a grid of two plots, `hp ~ mpg` and `wt ~ mpg` as well as showcase the value of `am`.

My initial response is to use `tidyr::gather` to group `hp` and `wt`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  gather(key, value, hp, wt)
```

Now instead of variables `hp` and `wt` you have variables `key` (which contain either 'hp' or 'wt' as values) and `value` which contains the respective value of 'hp' or 'wt'.

After that you build your initial plot (notice I pipe in the first statement as the data parameter to `ggplot`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  gather(key, value, hp, wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, color = as.factor(am)) + 
  geom_point()
```

In the aesthetics I have requested am (as a factor) to be used to distinguish color.

Now, you want a grid layout so `facet_wrap()` becomes your friend.

```
mtcars %>% 
  gather(key, value, hp, wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, color = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ key, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y")
```

With `facet_wrap` I'm asking ggplot2 to build a plot for each unique value of `key` which holds 'hp' and 'wt'. So I'll end up with two graphs on one plot. Since your original example was stacked, I use `nrow = 2`. And, since 'hp' and 'wt' are not similar in values you must use the `scales = "free_y"` parameter. This means that each graph will use its own y-axis to  accurately display the data.

And lastly if you don't want "as.factor(am)" as your legend title (and who does?), use `scale_color_discrete()`. We use color because that is what we assigned the `am` variable to (rather than fill, size, shape, etc.) and then discrete because `am` is a discrete variable.

So your code ends up like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  gather(key, value, hp, wt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, color = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ key, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = element_text("am")))
```

And your plot ends up like this:

[image]

If I misunderstood your question I'll be happy to edit as necessary.

Comment: A slight misunderstanding. I do not want all levels of "am" in one plot. In your example you have two plots in one multiplot. I am wanting 2 plots in one multiplot for am=0  and 2 plots in one multiplot for am=1. I would then like to save as pdf so that I have 2 plots on page 1 corresponding to am=0 and 2 plots on page 2 corresponding to am=1.